# Should I use Context Isolation with my Electron App

Tags: javascript, electron

My friend and I are almost done with [our project](https://github.com/Gabe-H/Gemini/tree/v4). It's basically a now playing/miniplayer app for Spotify. When I was checking the render process console, I had one more warning that I wanted to clear. It was about `worldSafeExecuteJavaScript` being true and how it's unsafe. I looked farther in to it and it turns out I need to turn on `contextIsolation` too. I researched more and found out I have that I can't use `require` in my render process. I tried looking up the documentation and I am confused. We want to make our app secure for the long run, especially since I'm in college and my friend working on it might get busy as his school ramps up; and also since `contextIsolation` will be true by default in Electron 12.

In our render processes javascript, we just need to require jQuery and ipcRenderer. How would we incorporate `contextBridge` (I think that's what its called), to import jQuery and ipcRenderer into our javascript for the render process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my application to work with `contextIsolation` on by using `contextBridge`. Here's my `main.js` `webPreferences` with the preload script:

```
    webPreferences: {
      worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js")
    },
```

and here's `preload.js` to import the `ipcRenderer`:

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'ipcRenderer',
    {
/*
Important note: This will get it working, 
but I'm going to make multiple methods for 
each time I'm using this to heighten security.
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/context-isolation#security-considerations
*/
      send: (channel, arg) => ipcRenderer.send(channel, arg),
      on: (event, data) => ipcRenderer.on(event, data)
    }
)
```

[To import jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63842132/10013136), I just imported it with `index.html`:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Gemini</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="macos.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css">
  </head>
```

I'm not sure if importing jQuery through the HTML is safer though.