# Import jQuery with contextBridge

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I'm trying to use `contextBridge` in Electron, but I keep getting an error when I try to `require('jQuery')` in `preload.js`. Here is my `preload.js`:

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
require('jQuery')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'ipcRenderer',
    {
      send: (channel, arg) => ipcRenderer.send(channel, arg),
      on: (event, data) => ipcRenderer.on(event, data)
    }
)
```

As soon as I put `require('jQuery')`, I get this error:

[image]

I want to import APIs like this since it improves security and `contextIsolation` will be enabled by default in later versions of Electron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea if this is secure or not, but I just imported jQuery from `index.html`:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Gemini</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self'">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="macos.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css">
  </head>
```

Comment: That's probably okay, no need to import jquery another way.